# How do you undelete a record?

Tags: case

I have accidentally deleted a support ticket within the salesforce support page.

There is a message saying I can recover it from the recycle bin, however I am unable to find it.

> The record you attempted to access has been deleted. The user who deleted this record may be able to recover it from the Recycle Bin. Deleted data is stored in the Recycle Bin for 15 days.

The salesforce administrator is not available for several days. Can anyone point me to where the Recycle Bin is located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*typically* your recycle bin link (by default) lives towards the bottom of your left hand side bar. But it is entirely likely this may have been customised away in many cases. I thought it would be worth noting as a potential answer to some people though.

[image: Recycle bin location]

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

By adding the following to the URL, I was able to find the recycle bin page

https://foobar.salesforce.com/search/UndeletePage

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gyV3AAI